# how to define python generic classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a class:

```
T = TypeVar('T')


class Stack(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: list[T] = []

    def push(self, item: T) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self) -> T:
        return self.items.pop()

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        return not self.items
```

but I can also do:

```
T = TypeVar('T')


class Stack:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Create an empty list with items of type T
        self.items: list[T] = []

    def push(self, item: T) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self) -> T:
        return self.items.pop()

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        return not self.items
```

1. what is the difference between these two samples?
2. which on should I use?

I tried running both, and both worked.

Comment: they are both the same thing.  The Generic is just a type hint

Comment: which on should i use?
 what is the difference between the 2?

Comment: @Alexander you couldn't have been further from the truth...

Comment: @xsaxsa  From my own experience and understanding... both classes should function identically so it really is up to you.  I personally am not a typing enthusiast and according to SUTerliakov my earliers statement coundn't have been further from the truth.  So you could also just ignore everything I am saying.

Comment: @SUTerliakov  does the answer joel has linked too sufficiently answer this question to your satisfaction?

Comment: @Alexander that answer is great on its own, and answers question 2, but this question is broader, because requests also explanation of another pattern - so not a clean dupe, IMO. (I'm a bit late, but done)

Answer (score 1):

### Type checking vs runtime

After writing this, I finally understood @Alexander point in first comment: whatever you write in annotations, it does not affect runtime, and your code is executed in the same way (sorry, I missed that you're looking just not from type checking perspective). This is core principle of python typing, as opposed to strongly typed languages (which makes it wonderful IMO): you can always say "I don't need types here - save my time and mental health". Type annotations are used to help some third-party tools, like `mypy` (type checker maintained by python core team) and IDEs. IDEs can suggest you something based on this information, and `mypy` checks whether your code can work if your types match the reality.

### Generic version

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

class Stack(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: list[T] = []

    def push(self, item: T) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self) -> T:
        return self.items.pop()

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        return not self.items
```

You can treat type variables like regular variables, but intended for "meta" usage and ignored (well, there are some runtime traces, but they exist primary for introspection purpose) on runtime. They are substituted once for every binding context (more about it - below), and can be defined only once per module scope.

The code above declares normal generic class with one type argument. Now you can say `Stack[int]` to refer to a stack of integers, which is great. Current definition allows either explicit typing or using implicit `Any` parametrization:

```py
# Explicit type
int_stack: Stack[int] = Stack()
reveal_type(int_stack)  # N: revealed type is "__main__.Stack[builtins.int]
int_stack.push(1)  # ok
int_stack.push('foo')  # E: Argument 1 to "push" of "Stack" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
reveal_type(int_stack.pop())  # N: revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

```py
# No type results in mypy error, similar to `x = []`
any_stack = Stack()  # E: need type annotation for any_stack
# But if you ignore it, the type becomes `Stack[Any]`
reveal_type(any_stack)  # N: revealed type is "__main__.Stack[Any]
any_stack.push(1)  # ok
any_stack.push('foo')  # ok too
reveal_type(any_stack.pop())  # N: revealed type is "Any"
```

To make the intended usage easier, you can allow initialization from iterable (I'm not covering the fact that you should be using `collections.deque` instead of list and maybe instead of this Stack class, assuming it is just a toy collection):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

class Stack(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, items: Iterable[T] | None) -> None:
        # Create an empty list with items of type T
        self.items: list[T] = list(items or [])
    ...

deduced_int_stack = Stack([1])
reveal_type(deduced_int_stack)  # N: revealed type is "__main__.Stack[builtins.int]"
```

To sum up, generic classes have some type variable bound to the class body. When you create an instance of such class, it can be parametrized with some type - it may be another type variable or some fixed type, like `int` or `tuple[str, Callable[[], MyClass[bool]]]`. Then all occurrences of `T` in its body (except for nested classes, which are perhaps out of "quick glance" explanation context) are replaced with this type (or `Any`, if it is not given and cannot be deduced). This type can be deduced iff at least one of `__init__` or `__new__` arguments has type referring to `T` (just `T` or, say, `list[T]`), and otherwise you have to specify it. Note that if you have `T` used in `__init__` of non-generic class, it is not very cool, although currently not disallowed.

Now, if you use `T` in some methods of generic class, it refers to that replaced value and results in typecheck errors, if passed types are not compatible with expected.

You can play with this example [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.990&python=3.10).

### Working outside of generic context

However, not all usages of type variables are related to generic classes. Fortunately, you cannot declare generic function with possibility to declare generic arg on calling side (like `function<T> fun(x: number): int` and `fun<string>(0)`), but there is enough more stuff. Let's begin with simpler examples - pure functions:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def func1() -> T:
    return 1
def func2(x: T) -> int:
    return 1
def func3(x: T) -> T:
    return x
def func4(x: T, y: T) -> int:
    return 1
```

First function is declared to return some value of **unbound** type T. It obviously makes no sense, and recent `mypy` versions even learned to mark it as error. Your function return depends only on arguments and external state - and type variable must be present there, right? You cannot also declare global variable of type `T` in module scope, because `T` is still unbound - and thus neither `func1` args nor module-scoped variables can depend on `T`.

Second function is more interesting. It does not cause `mypy` error, although still makes not very much sense: we can bind some type to `T`, but what is the difference between this and `func2_1(x: Any) -> int: ...`? We can speculate that now `T` can be used as annotation in function body, which can help in some corner case with type variable having upper bound, and I won't say it is impossible - but I cannot quickly construct such example, and have never seen such usage in proper context (it was always a mistake). Similar example is even explicitly referenced in PEP as valid.

The third and fourth functions are typical examples of type variables in functions. The third declares function returning the same type as it's argument.

The fourth function takes two arguments of the same type (arbitrary one). It is more useful if you have `T = TypeVar('T', bound=Something)` or `T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes)`: you can concatenate two arguments of type `T`, but cannot - of type `str | bytes`, like in the below example:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes)

def total_length(x: T, y: T) -> int:
    return len(x + y)
```

The most important fact about all examples above in this section: `T` doesnot have to be the same for different functions. You can call `func3(1)`, then `func3(['bar'])` and then `func4('foo', 'bar')`. `T` is `int`, `list[str]` and `str` in these calls - no need to match.

With this in mind your second solution is clear:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

class Stack:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Create an empty list with items of type T
        self.items: list[T] = []  # E: Type variable "__main__.T" is unbound  [valid-type]

    def push(self, item: T) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self) -> T:  # E: A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar  [type-var]
        return self.items.pop()
```

Here is `mypy` issue, discussing [similar case](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6520).

`__init__` says that we set attribute `x` to value of type `T`, but this `T` is lost later (`T` is scoped only within `__init__`) - so `mypy` rejects the assignment.

`push` is ill-formed and `T` has no meaning here, but it does not result in invalid typing situation, so is not rejected (type of argument is erased to `Any`, so you still can call `push` with some argument).

`pop` is invalid, because typechecker needs to know what `my_stack.pop()` will return. It could say "I give up - just have your Any", and will be perfectly valid (PEP does not enforce this). but `mypy` is more smart and denies invalid-by-design usage.

*Edge case: you can return `SomeGeneric[T]` with unbound `T`, for example, in factory functions*:

```
def make_list() -> list[T]: ...

mylist: list[str] = make_list()
```

*because otherwise type argument couldn't have been specified on calling site*

For better understanding of type variables and generics in python, I suggest you to read [PEP483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#defining-and-using-generic-types) and [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#instantiating-generic-classes-and-type-erasure) - usually PEPs are more like a boring standard, but these are really good as a starting point.

There are many edge cases omitted there, which still cause hot discussions in `mypy` team (and probably other typecheckers too) - say, type variables in staticmethods of generic classes, or binding in classmethods used as constructors - mind that they can be used on instances too. However, basically you can:

- have a TypeVar bound to class (`Generic` or `Protocol`, or some `Generic` subclass - if you subclass `Iterable[T]`, your class is already generic in `T`) - then all methods use the same `T` and can contain it in one or both sides
- or have a method-scoped/function-scoped type variable - then it's useful if repeated in the signature more than once (not necessary "clean" - it may be parametrizing another generic)
- or use type variables in generic aliases (like `LongTuple = tuple[T, T, T, T]` - then you can do `x: LongTuple[int] = (1, 2, 3, 4)`
- or do something more exotic with type variables, which is probably out of scope