# How to annotate a user-defined collection in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I've created a collection type:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class MyCollection(Sequence):
    pass
```

and I want to annotate object of my class like this:

```
obj: MyCollection[int] = MyCollection()
```

How to achieve this?

I wrote:

```
obj: MyCollection[int] = MyCollection()
```

But IntelliSense only specifies `MyCollection` not `MyCollection[int]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to define python generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74472798/how-to-define-python-generic-classes)

Comment: If all you want to do is have a generic subclass of `Sequence`, then literally all you need to do is do `T = TypeVar("T")` `class MyCollection(Sequence[T]): ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `typing` it provides runtime support for type hints, for user-defined generic collection, you can use `typing.Generic` and `typing.TypeVar`

Here is an example:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from collections.abc import Sequence

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyCollection(Sequence, Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def add(self, item: T):
        self.data.append(item)

obj: MyCollection[int] = MyCollection()
obj.add(1)
```

Comment: Basically, genericity isn't inherited. `class MyCollection(Sequence)` is the same as `class MyCollection(Sequence[Any])`, not the generic definition shown here.

Comment: Is it really intended to use `T` only for `add`, leaving inerited methods with `Any` type?  To propagate T to subclassed generic, you need to inherit from `Sequence[T]`. For Sequence this may be not important (only `__getitem__` uses `T`, AFAIC), this will show up for e.g. `MutableSequence`. Try to remove `[T]` after `MutableSequence` [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=b38b7d113b8b3e0bee743173aa2a836e), and see the expected error on the last line disappear.

Comment: This is a bad solution, and not just because it is unnecessarily verbose. It actually **erases** the genericity of `collections.abc.Sequence` (cementing the item type to `Any`). To get it back, you would have to annotate `__getitem__` **and** the inherited methods utilizing the type argument, such as `__iter__`, with `T`. You would basically have to re-implement the sequence protocol from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

To learn about user-defined generic types, read [this section of PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types).

You apparently want to subclass the `Sequence` [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes). Note that `collections.abc.Sequence` is **already generic**. That means to retain genericity in a subclass, you simply need to pass a type variable to `Sequence` during inheritance.

You just need to take care to implement the overloaded signatures of [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) properly because it should accept indices *and* slices and return either a sequence item *or* a sub-sequence respectively.

Example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Iterable, Sequence
from typing import TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")


class MyCollection(Sequence[T]):
    def __init__(self, data: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        self.items = tuple(data)

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> T: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> MyCollection[T]: ...

    def __getitem__(self, index: int | slice) -> T | MyCollection[T]:
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return MyCollection(self.items[index])
        return self.items[index]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.items)
```

Try that with [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=69193d3ac8962529d69440ba53bdf4a9) (playground):

```py
s = MyCollection([10, 20, 30])
reveal_type(s)
reveal_type(s[0])
reveal_type(s[0:])
reveal_type(iter(s))
```

The output will be the following:

```
note: Revealed type is "MyCollection[builtins.int]"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
note: Revealed type is "MyCollection[builtins.int]"
note: Revealed type is "typing.Iterator[builtins.int]"
```

Notice how the types are correctly inferred without the need for an explicit annotation during usage. Even the iterator item type is correctly inferred because `Sequence[T]` is set up to return `Iterator[T]` from its [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method.

This means, when `s` is e.g. of type `MyCollection[int]` and you do `for item in s: ...` and the static type checker will infer `item` to be of type `int`.